# I want to create a string from the first word of each tuple in a list of tuples

Tags: python, dataframe, tuples

I have the following dataframe

```
data = [[1,[('car', 'NN'), ('park', 'VB'), ('in', 'PRP'), ('lobby', 'NN')]], [0, [('Dany', 'NN'), ('has', 'VB'), ('an', 'CC'), ('apple', 'NN')]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['sen', 'col'])
```

Expected Output:

| sen | col |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "car park in lobby" |
| 2 | "Dany has an apple" |

Comment: `df.col.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(map(lambda y: y[0], x)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [[1,[('car', 'NN'), ('park', 'VB'), ('in', 'PRP'), ('lobby', 'NN')]], [2, [('Dany', 'NN'), ('has', 'VB'), ('an', 'CC'), ('apple', 'NN')]]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['sen', 'col'])
df.col = df.col.apply(lambda l: ' '.join([e[0] for e in l]))
print(df)
```

prints

| index | sen | col |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | car park in lobby |
| 1 | 2 | Dany has an apple |